# (Game Engine) How to restrict character movement to linear paths

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm making a Pac-Man clone to familiarize myself with the game engine and I can't figure out how to limit the area the player/enemies can move in without introducing other problems. If I use a navigation mesh they kind of slide around clumsily instead of moving in straight lines parallel to the the x/y axis like in the original Pac-Man.

I've made a simple mesh (highlighted in orange) that shows the paths the characters should travel over.
[image: Path is highlighted in orange]

Is there any way I can restrict their movement so they're always located at some point on this path or am I better off just using a ton of logic bricks to handle each turn at each corner individually?

Comment: Can't think of a nice way tot do this with logic bricks without being hack. do you know Python?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried incrementing motion? You might try using a setup like the one in the image below to increment the motion of the characters (Although you can set the frequency extremely low) and then adding a non-rendering collision mesh ahead of the character that rotates them when they're about to hit a wall.

Just set the motion value to the number of blender units per grid space on your map, an that should do it!

[image: Screenshot demonstrating logic brick layout for incremental motion.]

Hopefully this helps! Just a quick aside, if the motion winds up being too fast, try halfing the value for motion. That'll slow it down while still preserving the grid-based motion.